Как зажимать кнопки мыши на Godot?
Я переносил игру со Scratch на Godot. Хотел сделать удар. И он работает! Но странно (должно быть так).Игрок атакует только когда я НАЖИМАЮ а не ЗАЖИМАЮ, и то не всегда. Список действий: 
Код:
extends CharacterBody2D

var speed = 5

var KickVar = false

func _physics_process(delta):
    $".".look_at(get_global_mouse_position())
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("KeyInpUP"):
        position.y -= speed
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("KeyInpDOWN"):
        position.y += speed
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("KeyInpLEFT"):
        position.x -= speed
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("KeyInpRIGHT"):
        position.x += speed
    
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("MouseInpLB"):
        kick()
        
func kick():
    KickVar = true
    $Base/Hands/HandAnim.play("Kick")
    KickVar = false
    


Попробуйте заменить эти строки:
if Input.is_action_just_pressed("MouseInpLB"):
    kick()

На такие:
if Input.get_action_strength("MouseInpLB"):
    kick()

is_action_just_pressed - возвращает true если кнопка нажалась.
а get_action_strength - если кнопка вообще нажата.

Спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли!
